# Búsqueda al instante

Tags: html, css, asp.net, script

Buen día, tengo una duda, ando desarrollando una aplicación web en asp.net y MySQL (Uso HTML & CSS) y quiero tener un textbox que lo llamo txtSearch.text que al momento de poner una palabra me muestre información relacionada, la información esta en GridView en el cual ya llame la información por medio de una consulta SQL la cual es la siguiente:

```
try
        {
            string cmd = string.Format("select * from DIRECCIONES_ACCESO_REMOTO order by IDP");
            DataSet dt = KeyConnection.Start(cmd);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.Visible = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('OCURRIO UN ERROR, CONTACTAR AL DESARROLLADOR');</script>");
        }introducir el código aquí
```

Estuve investigando y vi que con un script se puede hacer la búsqueda "caliente/instante"

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#txtSearch").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#GridView1").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Que seria ese, pero no me funciona, en cambio al tratar de poner mas de 3 caracteres me quita toda la información del GridView, no estoy muy relacionado con script, si me pudieran echar la mano:)

De antemano Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Ayuda Razita Me Quede Estancado En Esto :c

Comment: que lenguaje usas?

Comment: Estoy usando ASP.NET, MySQL, HTML y CSS